# Swap variable names and field names in a set of structs, so the field names become the struct names and vice versa?

Tags: matlab, struct

I have a set of structs that all have the same field names. For example structs `A`, `B`, and `C` all have field names `name` and `section`. Is there a way to rearrange this organization of data so that the data goes from:

```
A.name = 'bb';
A.section = 199;
B.name = 'joe';
B.section = 101;
C.name = 'rob';
C.section = 33;
```

to this:

```
name =
A: 'bb'
B: 'joe'
C: 'rob'

section = 
A: 199
B: 101
C: 33
```

The current code I have, for example, operates like this:

```
% ORIGINAL STRUCTS
A.name = 'bb';
A.section = 199;
B.name = 'joe';
B.section = 101;
C.name = 'rob';
C.section = 33;

% CREATE VARIABLE NAMES FOR NEW STRUCTS
oldFNames = fieldnames(A); % old field names

oldVNames{1} = varname(A); % old variable names
oldVNames{2} = varname(B);
oldVNames{3} = varname(C);

% RESTRUCTURE STRUCTS (SWITCH FIELDNAMES AND VARIABLE NAMES)
for j = 1:length(oldFNames)
  for k = 1:length(oldVNames)
    eval([oldFNames{j} '.' oldVNames{k} ' = ' oldVNames{k} '.' oldFNames{j}]);
  end
end

function out = varname(var) % Function to get variable name
out = inputname(1);
end
```

I find the hack to use the `varname` function to be not great, and I don't know whether there is a way to make it easily adaptable to the number of variables I have. Any input on how to simplify this procedure would be great. Thanks.

Comment: [_Keep data out of your variable names_](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201112/keep_data_out_of_your_variable_names.html)

Comment: I think what you want is a struct array like this: `S(1).element='A';S(1).name='bb'; element(1).section=199;` etc. Or better a [table](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html).

Comment: You may be suffering from an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/52738). The solution I gave below will work, but there's probably a better way to organize your data in general that would avoid such difficulties (i.e. storing everything in structures or cell arrays instead of many variables).

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to do it *all* in a function, instead of just using a function to get the input variable name. Here's one solution:

```
function invert_struct(varargin)

  varNames = arrayfun(@inputname, 1:nargin, 'UniformOutput', false);  % Get input names
  s = [varargin{:}];       % Combine inputs into a structure array
  for f = fieldnames(s).'  % Loop over fields
    assignin('caller', f{:}, cell2struct({s.(f{:})}, varNames, 2));
  end

end
```

And you would call it like so, with however many inputs you like:

```
invert_struct(A, B, C, ...);
```

The function uses [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to create your new variables in the calling function and [`cell2struct`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) to create a new structure from your field data and old variable names. Note that it also makes use of [dynamic field names](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html).